# Applescript fonction : «script» doesn’t understand the message

Tags: applescript, script

I have a script which work all the time when it's running outside a function

```
tell application "System Events"
        tell process "theapp"
            set frontmost to true
            delay 0.2
            
            set THEListMenu to click pop up button "THE States" of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "Prism" of application process "theapp" of application "System Events"
        end tell
    end tell
```

however when I run it in a function, it always work fine once, then I always have an error:

```
TheListMenu()
on TheListMenu()
     tell application "System Events"
                tell process "theapp"
                    set frontmost to true
                    delay 0.2
                    
                    set THEListMenu to click pop up button "THE States" of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "Prism" of application process "theapp" of application "System Events"
                end tell
            end tell
end TheListMenu
```

> Script Error  «script» doesn’t understand the “ TheListMenu” message.
> Result:
> error "«script» doesn’t understand the “AUXListMenu” message." number
> -1708 from «script»

I don't understand what going wrong as it's the exact same code...
I initially though that the issue was because the app wasn't focused so I try to "activate" and then after "set frontmost to true" but again it's work fine when outside the function.

How could I solve this?

Update :
just for a example I'm doing the same with the mail app

```
ClickFolderInMail()

on ClickFolderInMail()
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Mail"
            set frontmost to true
            delay 1
            
            set ClickFolderInMail to click menu button 1 of toolbar 1 of window "Inbox (8 messages)"
        end tell
    end tell
end ClickFolderInMail
```

Update 2

This work fine every time I run the script

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Calendar"
        set frontmost to true
        delay 1
        
        lick button "Calendars" of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "Calendar"

        
    end tell
end tell
```

however this only work once and then produce the same error

> «script» doesn’t understand the “calendarEx” message.

```
calendarEx()

on calendarEx()
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Calendar"
            set frontmost to true
            delay 1
            
            lick button "Calendars" of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "Calendar"

            
        end tell
    end tell
end calendarEx
```

Comment: What is the actual name of the _application_ `"theapp"`?

Comment: Since you are already telling **System Events** to `tell process "theapp"` you do not need `of application process "theapp" of application "System Events"` as a part of `set THEListMenu to click pop up button "THE States" of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window "Prism"`. It's unnecessary redundant coding and in some cases can cause errors.

Comment: Thanks @user3439894, yes fair enough, I usually just copy the result but you right, I removed the unnecessary code. I updated my question with an example with the Mail app which have the same issue

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? -- **Again!** What is the actual name of the application `"theapp"?

Comment: Your Update example returns: **error** "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu button 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of process "Mail". Invalid index." and is not at all the same error your getting in your other _code_!  "doesn’t understand" and "Invalid index" are not the same error.

Comment: Catalina (10.15.7 (19H2)) the app is an internal app, this is why I updated with the same example using mail.app -- regarding mail I assume that might depend on the mail configuration, I'll try to find a better exemple

Comment: I don't know how you can say "This work fine every time I run the script" with the _code_ in Update 2 as it doesn't work at all because you can't `lick button`, and errors with "**Syntax Error** Expected end of line, etc. but found class name." and even fixing it to `click button` it then works without issue as standalone _code_ or wrapped in a _handler_, every time on my system.

Comment: Lolz.  Tell AppleScript to `lick my button` 

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue  which is "set clickBreak to click"
Removing "set clickBreak" resolve the issue.

Comment: There is no "set clickBreak to click" in any of the _code_ you posted!